# my laravel query is returning only the last record in the database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel

iam doing a search criteria for a website , the problem iam facing that if in the database i have more than driver of the same name , my query is only returning the last record it found , 
first of all iam getting from the user the input , and search in a table called drivers , for a record containing the same as the input he enters , code :

```
if(!empty($name)||!empty($policynum)||!empty($platenum)||!empty($platecode)) // ** if one of name or policy# or platenum or platecode  is set ** //
{
$query = DB::table('drivers');
if(!empty($name))
$query -> where('driverName',$name);
if(!empty($policynum))
$query -> where('policyNumber',$policynum);
if(!empty($platenum))
$query -> where('plateNumber',$platenum);
if(!empty($platecode))
$query -> where('plateCode',$platecode);

$result = $query->get();
 $result=json_encode($result,true);
 $result=json_decode($result,true);
 }                                // --- end of if 4 inputs set --- //
```

after that i get the drivers , i have an attribute in the driver data base called accident id , so now i have to go to the accidents database table , and search for an accidents that have id same as the accident id , code :

```
if(count($result)>0 && empty($expname))   // if result array returns >0 results and exp-name empty //

{
for($x=0;$x<count($result);$x++)
$accident= accident::where('id',$result[$x]['accidentId'])
->get(); 
return $accident; 
}
```

so iam using for loop to traverse all the results i have get from the drivers table , to see if any result from driver table have same id in the accident table , and if found i want to get all the accident row , and return it , and i put it in a table as follows :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="accident in accidents" > <!-- -->
                <td>{{accident.accidentRecord}}</td>
                <td>{{accident.expertId}}</td>
                <td>{{accident.address}}</td>
                <td>{{accident.date}} --  -- {{accident.time}}</td>
                <td>{{accident.completedDate}}</td>
```

and accident js code if needed :

```
$scope.search=function(accident)
{
  $http({
      method:'GET',
      url:'getAccident',
      params: {accident:accident}
  })
      .success(function(data){
          $scope.accidents=data;
          console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(err){
          console.log(err);
      })
};
```

but the table show only the last row in my database that have same id , not all the rows , can anybody help ?

php function output ($accident) :

> [[{"id":1,"accidentFloor":"","accidentRecord":"rexord test","address":"haret hreik","location":"no location","region":"","colleague":"","policeMan":"","roadDirection":"","roadType":"","roadNumbers":"","roadWidth":"","date":"2017-04-12","time":"16:28:29","vision":"","weatherCondition":"","expertId":1,"accidentGenerationNumber":"2017-04-1216:28:291","completedDate":"","freeDescription":"","created_at":"2017-04-12 16:28:29","updated_at":"2017-04-12 16:28:29","deleted_at":null}],[{"id":1,"accidentFloor":"","accidentRecord":"rexord test","address":"haret hreik","location":"no location","region":"","colleague":"","policeMan":"","roadDirection":"","roadType":"","roadNumbers":"","roadWidth":"","date":"2017-04-12","time":"16:28:29","vision":"","weatherCondition":"","expertId":1,"accidentGenerationNumber":"2017-04-1216:28:291","completedDate":"","freeDescription":"","created_at":"2017-04-12 16:28:29","updated_at":"2017-04-12 16:28:29","deleted_at":null}],[{"id":1,"accidentFloor":"","accidentRecord":"rexord test","address":"haret hreik","location":"no location","region":"","colleague":"","policeMan":"","roadDirection":"","roadType":"","roadNumbers":"","roadWidth":"","date":"2017-04-12","time":"16:28:29","vision":"","weatherCondition":"","expertId":1,"accidentGenerationNumber":"2017-04-1216:28:291","completedDate":"","freeDescription":"","created_at":"2017-04-12 16:28:29","updated_at":"2017-04-12 16:28:29","deleted_at":null}],[{"id":3,"accidentFloor":"","accidentRecord":"bir al abed","address":"borj","location":"33.8591245,35.5110078","region":"","colleague":"","policeMan":"","roadDirection":"","roadType":"\u0645\u0646\u0639\u0637\u0641","roadNumbers":"2","roadWidth":"","date":"2017-05-01","time":"13:21:26","vision":"","weatherCondition":"","expertId":1,"accidentGenerationNumber":"2017-05-0113:21:261","completedDate":"","freeDescription":"","created_at":"2017-05-01 13:21:26","updated_at":"2017-05-01 13:21:26","deleted_at":null}]]

console output :

> (4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
>   0
>   :
>   Array(1)
>   1
>   :
>   Array(1)
>   2
>   :
>   Array(1)
>   3
>   :
>   Array(1)
>   length
>   :
>   4
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Array(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop

```
for($x=0;$x<count($result);$x++)
$accident= accident::where('id',$result[$x]['accidentId'])
->get();
```

is over writing over the same `$accident` variable again and again. Hence you only get the last record always in the variable.
Change the if condition and the loop to this:

```
$accidents = [];
if(count($result)>0 && empty($expname))   // if result array returns >0 results and exp-name empty //
{
    for($x=0;$x<count($result);$x++)
        $accidents[] = accident::where('id',$result[$x]['accidentId'])->get(); 
    return $accidents; 
}
```

`$accidents` contains all the accidents data.

Comment: thats right , i tried to add $accident[$x] , so it may add them to the array , but still didnt work

Comment: okay , that was somehow helpful , iam now getting in my table 3 rows , which is the same number of the rows contaning that name in my database , but as a second issue , the table is empty , as i see in the console , its returning 3 arrays but empty

Comment: Just do a `print_r` for the `$accidents` variable and see what it shows.

Comment: it shows the 3 rows i want them , so the query worked , but why iam getting empty rows in the table ? , i posted up the html part which iam filling the table thru , do you think i have to edit anything in it ?

Comment: If you show me what the `$accidents` variable contains, I'll help you figure out the error in the html.

Comment: Either that or show me the `console.log($scope.accidents)` output.

Comment: okay i will post up the console output , and the output of  php function iam running

Comment: i posted the output

Comment: I'm not sure how you finally wrote your php code but its creating an extra array for each table row. Try changing the angular code to `accident.0.accidentRecord` or `accident[0]accidentRecord`, I'm not really sure.

Comment: thanks very much for your help , i just have to edit the angular code to become : accident[0]['accidentRecord'] , thank you

Comment: Glad to help :)